# How to add a line to a scatter plot? (Java, jmathplot)

Tags: java, scatter-plot

with this code I am able to draw a scatter plot.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.math.plot.*;
public class ScatterPlotExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] x = new double[] { 60 };
    double[] y = new double[] { 50 };

    // create your PlotPanel (you can use it as a JPanel)
    Plot2DPanel plot = new Plot2DPanel();

    // add a line plot to the PlotPanel

    plot.addScatterPlot("teeeeest", x, y);


    // put the PlotPanel in a JFrame, as a JPanel
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("a plot panel");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setContentPane(plot);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Two questions:

How can I make the axes ranges from 1 to 100? 
How can I draw into that scatter plot a horizontal and a vertical line at x = 0.4 and y = 0.7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to set X axis range:

  `plot.setFixedBounds(0,1,100)` **->** (where 0 means X, 1 means Y)
- to add an horizontal line at Y=49.5:

  `plot.addPlotable(new Line(Color.red, 
  new double[]{plot.plotCanvas.base.getMinBounds()[0],49.5},
  new double[]{plot.plotCanvas.base.getMaxBounds()[0],49.5}));`